# Restrict Amazon S3 access to single HTTPS host

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, https, reverse-proxy

I want to proxy an Amazon S3 bucket through our reverse proxy (Nginx).

For higher security, I want to forbid the read access to the bucket to anything except of the HTTPS host at which I ran the proxy.

Is there a way to configure Amazon S3 for this task?

Please provide the configuration.

I considered to add a password in S3 bucket name, but it is not a solution, because we need also signed uploads to the bucket and so the bucket name will be publicly available.

Comment: Where is your Reverse Proxy? Is it running on an Amazon EC2 instance, or is it on the Internet? Does it have a single, unique public IP address (as opposed to being behind a NAT/firewall)?

Comment: If you have control over which IAM users/roles have access to the bucket then you can control it that way. Simply launch the nginx instance with an IAM role allowing access to the bucket but launch the other compute with roles that do not have that S3 permission.

Comment: @jarmod The question is how to add IAM role to Nginx

Comment: Also: Can it be done with CORS? If I restrict access with CORS, should the bucket be world-readable or not? (Sorry that I repeat, but I want to be sure my question is heard.)

Comment: Launching EC2 instances with IAM roles is well documented and a quick search will provide everything you need.

Comment: @jarmod But we run our proxy not on a EC2 instance, but another (non-Amazon) VPS hoster

Comment: OK then you may want to supply IAM user credentials to that system, or preferably provide a backend API that the nginx host can authenticate to periodically to retrieve STS temporary credentials. Use those credentials to access the S3 bucket.

Comment: "supply IAM user credentials to that system" - what do you mean and how to do this? "backend API" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If your reverse proxy has a Public IP address, then you would add this policy to the Amazon S3 bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.22/32"}
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

This grants permissions to `GetObject` if the request is coming from the specific IP address. Amazon S3 is private by default, so this is granting access only in that particular situation. You will also want to grant access to IAM Users/Groups (via IAM, *not* a Bucket Policy) so that bucket content can be updated.

See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: But is it protected against IP faking attacks? Can it be secured with HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, Amazon S3 can use HTTPS. As for IP attacks -- if they are using a fake IP address, then they will never receive the message in response!

Comment: Can it be done with CORS instead? If I restrict access with CORS, should the bucket be world-readable or not?

Comment: Restricting access to the HTTPS host which contains my proxy.

Comment: That has nothing to do with CORS. If you wish for your proxy to be the only resource to access your S3 bucket, you need to use a policy like the one I provided above.

Comment: What does it have nothing to do with CORS? It looks like that CORS can restrict access to a given HTTPS host. See `<AllowedOrigin>` in CORS

Comment: You say if IP is fake the response will not be received. I think a hacker can indeed do it if he is in the middle between S3 and our proxy. Is there any way to secure it with HTTPS? particularly what's about CORS?